# Where is the door for the green gemstones in Steven Universe: Attack the Light?

Tags: steven-universe-attack-the-light

I forgot the location and my searching has availed me naught. It's somewhere in the first two worlds but I'm not seeing it going back through them.

Note that I'm not talking about the energy gates that have to be opened with the keys. I'm talking about the door that has to be opened with the backpack item "green gemstone".

Answer (score 2):

I found it in 2-4.

[image]

It is to the left of the exit warp.

[image]